# Derive the closed form of a probability expression

Tags: probability, logistic, categorical-data, estimation, gumbel-distribution

Consider the following probability
$$
A\equiv Pr\Big (\delta_1+v+\lambda \epsilon_1\geq \delta_2+v+\lambda \epsilon_2  \text{, } \delta_1+v+\lambda \epsilon_1\geq \epsilon_0 \Big )
$$
where

- $\lambda\in (0,1)$ is a known scalar.
- $\delta_1,\delta_2$ are known real scalars.
- $\{v,\epsilon_0, \epsilon_1, \epsilon_2\}$ are mutually independent random variables.
- Each of $\{\epsilon_0,\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\}$ has a [Gumbel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution) distribution with location $0$ and scale $1$
- $v$ is distributed such that $v+\lambda\epsilon_1$ has a Gumbel distribution with location $0$ and scale $1$.

**Question:** Could you help me to show that

$$
A= \frac{\exp(\delta_1/\lambda)}{1+ \exp(\delta_1/\lambda)+\exp(\delta_2/\lambda)}
$$

---

**My attempt:** These are my derivations which, however, lead to a different result that the one conjectured above.  Where is the mistake?

**Step 1:** $A$ can be rewritten as

$$
A=\underbrace{Pr\Big (\delta_1+v+\lambda \epsilon_1\geq \delta_2+v+\lambda \epsilon_2\Big)}_{\equiv B} \times \underbrace{Pr \Big(\max\{\delta_1+v+\lambda \epsilon_1, \delta_2+v+\lambda \epsilon_2\}\geq \epsilon_0 \Big )}_{\equiv C}
$$

**Step 2:**
$$
B=Pr\Big (\delta_1+\lambda \epsilon_1\geq \delta_2+\lambda \epsilon_2\Big)=Pr\Big (\underbrace{\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2}_{\text{Logistic with scale $1$ and loc. $0$}}\geq \frac{\delta_2}{\lambda}-\frac{\delta_1}{\lambda}\Big)=\frac{\exp(\delta_1/\lambda)}{\exp(\delta_1/\lambda)+\exp(\delta_2/\lambda)}
$$

**Step 3:**
$$
C=Pr \Big(v+\lambda \max\{\frac{\delta_1}{\lambda}+ \epsilon_1, \frac{\delta_2}{\lambda}+\epsilon_2\}\geq \epsilon_0 \Big )
$$
where
$$
\max\{\frac{\delta_1}{\lambda}+ \epsilon_1, \frac{\delta_2}{\lambda}+\epsilon_2\}\sim \text{Gumbel with scale $1$ and location $I\equiv  \log(\exp(\delta_1/\lambda)+\exp(\delta_2 / \lambda))$}
$$

Therefore, we can replace $\max\{\frac{\delta_1}{\lambda}+ \epsilon_1, \frac{\delta_2}{\lambda}+\epsilon_2\}$ with $I+ \eta$, where $\eta$ is distributed as a Gumbel with scale $1$ and location $0$.

Hence,
$$
C=Pr \Big(v+\lambda \eta-\epsilon_0\geq -\lambda I \Big )
$$

**Step 4:**
Note that by our assumptions on $v$, $v+\lambda\eta$ is distributed as a Gumbel with scale $1$ and location $0$. Hence, as in Step 1, $v+\lambda \eta-\epsilon_0$ is distributed as a Logistic with scale $1$ and location $0$.

Therefore,

$$
C=\frac{\exp(\lambda I)}{1+\exp(\lambda I)}=\frac{(\exp(\delta_1/\lambda)+\exp(\delta_2/\lambda))^{\lambda}}{1+(\exp(\delta_1/\lambda)+\exp(\delta_2/\lambda))^{\lambda}}
$$

**Step 5:** I combine the results

$$
A=\frac{\exp(\delta_1/\lambda)}{\exp(\delta_1/\lambda)+\exp(\delta_2/\lambda)}\times \frac{(\exp(\delta_1/\lambda)+\exp(\delta_2/\lambda))^{\lambda}}{1+(\exp(\delta_1/\lambda)+\exp(\delta_2/\lambda))^{\lambda}}
$$

which does not seem to simplify as desired.

Comment: Consider the case $J=2,$ because it reveals all the essential features of the problem.

Comment: @whuber Following your suggestions, I have rewritten the problem and added my derivations. I'm getting a result different from what I conjectured. Am I doing a mistake in the proof, or the conjectured result was in fact wrong?

Comment: In Step 1, what justifies writing the expression $A$ as a product of probabilities?

Comment: I took that from the Nested Logit model framework.Think about an individual choosing between three alternatives, in order to maximise her utility. Alternative $1$ produces utility $\delta_1+v+\lambda\epsilon_1$; alternative $2$ produces utility $\delta_2+v+\lambda\epsilon_2$; alternative $3$ produces utility $\epsilon_0$. Suppose that alternatives $1$ and $2$ belong to nest $\alpha$. Alternative $3$ belongs to nest $\beta$.

Comment: Hence, $A=Pr(\text{individual chooses alternative  1})=Pr(\text{individual chooses alternative 1| individual chooses nest $\alpha$})\times Pr(\text{individual chooses nest $\alpha$})$

Comment: The first term of the product is $B$. The second term of the product is $C$.

Comment: Unfortunately, the information you supply in your question is insufficient to justify this multiplication.